open explorer to specific directory from git bash
When I execute this in Git bash windows on windows ten
foo_man@computer MINGW64 /c/www/root/images/
$ explorer /c/www/root/images/

It opens up explorer, but not to the directory c:\www\root\images.
How do I open up a specific directory in windows explorer from git bash

you need /cygdrive/c/www/root/images/
The following works:
cd /cygdrive/c/www/root/images/
explorer .

this could be an alias or script
explorer $(cygpath -w '/cygdrive/c/www/root/images/')

also works. The $( ) syntax uses the output of the command as an option for explorer

I use explorer /e,. to open explorer in the current directory of the shell. I have explorer () { $(cygpath -u 'C:\Windows\explorer.exe') "$*" } in .bashrc.

This does not work for me. explorer requires the directory to be in Windows format.

. is the universal (e.g. Windows, Linux, Cygwin, MingGW) shortcut for the current directory, Of course, you need to use $(cygpath -w <Posix path>) (or -wa) for other paths, (except for .. in most cases).

I guess I was really referring to the "$*" for the directory name.

This link might help https://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/windows/shell/explorer/cmdline.htm
